# Не работает setReferencePoints()

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Если я добавляю транзитные точки через editor мышкой, то при последующей попытке смены адресов маршрута через multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints([ [],[] ]) приходит ошибка: 
`{code: 500, message: "internal server error"}` и адрес не меняется.

Если транзитные не добавлять, то все нормально.

Надеюсь я полностью описал проблему. Как мне изменить адреса маршрута все таки?

Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/helight59/o120gdhb/

Comment: Соберите минимальный пример воспроизводящий проблему на jsfiddle. Пока непонятно в какую сторону копать)

Comment: @se0ga добавил пример

Comment: @se0ga ждать помощи?

Comment: setReferencePoints вторым параметром принимает виа-точки, если вы его не передаёте то он передаёт предыдущее состояние то есть первая точка - это виа-точка. Передаём второй параметр и всё работает https://jsfiddle.net/spwfq7j2/

Comment: @se0ga фух. Можете кидать как ответ. Добавьте в docs пожалуйста это. Я часа 2 промаялся. Варианты перебрал и решил уже перезапрашивать multiRoute, но ваш ответ решил вопрос.

Comment: В документации описано что можно передавать в качестве параметров https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRouteModel-docpage/#method_detail__setReferencePoints

Comment: @se0ga не информации о том, что это обязательный параметр в случаях, как мой. Часа 2 не мог найти ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setReferencePoints вторым параметром принимает виа-точки, если вы его не передаёте то он передаёт предыдущее состояние, то есть в вашем случае первая точка - это виа-точка и поэтому возникает ошибка. Передаём второй параметр и всё работает

```
multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints([
      [55.789085, 37.493621],
      [55.789424, 37.481948]
    ], []);
```

jsfiddle.net/spwfq7j2